# parameter declaration expected error in javascript

Tags: javascript, solidity

In my code it is showing an error for function() stating parameter declarartion expected

I tried giving different parameters inside the function

$ (function() {

}

Parameter declaration expected

Comment: You don't have a `)` at the end to balance the `(` after `$`. It's probably worth working through some basic JavaScript tutorials to get an idea of the basic syntax of the language.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot an ")"

```
$ (function() {

});
```

Comment: Typos don't need *answers*. Just comments and close votes.

Comment: This comment above is what's wrong with Stack Overflow